# Powershell command failing

Tags: powershell-2.0

So, I want to write a powershell command that lists all the PIDS of all services within a range of numbers. So, it would display only pids greater than 5 but less than 35.

```
Get-Process | where-object {$_.WorkingSet -gt 5} | where-object {$_.WorkingSet -lt 35}
```

I am not sure the -lt is even valid to be honest- but can someone at least tell me if I am close or on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Close. I'd do this:

```
Get-Process | where-object {$_.WorkingSet -gt 5 -and $_.WorkingSet -lt 35}
```